# Display data from database by selecting two date range which are selected from textbox in c#.net VS 2008

Tags: c#

please help me..
    i have following c# code :

```
    textBox1.text=11/05/2014;
    textBox2.text=11/06/2014;

    if(sdr.HasRows==true)

    {
            while(sdr.Read())
            {
               date should be display in label
               date should be display in textbox
            }

     }
```

my database have one table which contain some data as on some date..
    i want to display those data which are on some particular date by selecting date range.
    if data is not available then date will be display "No data".
    So.can any one help me to solve this query...please send demo code for that...

Comment: Convert your textbox values to `DateTime` and check your datatabase value is between these dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First assign your textbox values to 2 Datetime format variables.

```
Datetime DateFrom = Convert.toDatetime(textBox1.text);
Datetime DateTo = Convert.toDatetime(textBox2.text);
```

Then you have to make an SQL Query and call this from your C# code, within the event handler(e.x. button_click)

SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.table WHERE field between @DateFrom and @DateTo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Public void HasRows(SqlConnection connection)
 {
  using (connection)
    {
    DateTime StartDate=Date.Parse(textBox1.text.ToString());
    DateTime EndDate=Date.Parse(textBox2.text.ToString());

    String StrQuery="select *  from <TableName> where  DateColumn between

     '"+ StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") +"' and '"+ EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")                  +"'";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(StrQuery,  connection);
    connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {

          Label1.Text=reader["field_a"].ToString();//date should be display in label
          txtBox3.Text=reader["field_b".ToString(); //date should be display in textbox
        }
    }
    else
    {
      Response.Write("No Data Found");
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my question...it works ..but one query the code is displaying data on label1 and textbox3 only..i want to display data on those label and textBox which are fetch from database ..Suppose, i select 01/05/2014 to 05/05/2014.my data base having data like as 02/05/2014 => "shailesh",03/05/2014 => "kishor".so when i click on button then it will display 01/05/2014 => No data,02/05/2014 => "shailesh",03/05/2014 => "kishor",04/05/2014 => No data,05/05/2014 => No data..like this...so can u help me for that..?

Comment: Assign it ,where you want to assign your data